# Query that selects every element of a type in a hierarchy

Tags: sql

I have two database tables.

```
  Table A              Table B

  Continent text       City                Text
  Country   text       Citizen ID (unique) Int    
  City      text
```

How do I write a query that will return a row for every city within a particular continent in the form of Continent, Country, City, and (number of citizens per city)?

What if I wanted to restrict it further such as for every city within a particular continent and country?

I'm having trouble visualizing the query as something other than a series of nested for loops. I'm kinda lost on how to join the tables in such a way where I can do a count of citizen id and get the necessary geographic restrictions. I apologize in advance if I'm just being a bit dense.

Comment: Its unclear what are you asking can you add sum input data and expected output ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the which DBMS you are using so I am assuming `MSServer`. You can apply the `Join` and `Count` to get the `row for every city within a particular continent in the form of Continent, Country, City, and (number of citizens per city)`

```
   SELECT
         a.Continent,
         a.Country,
         a.City,
         Count(b.CitizenID) AS 'NumberOfCitizens'
  FROM
     tableA a Join tableB b
     ON a.City = b.City
  WHERE
     a.Continent = 'Yourcontinent'
  Group By
      a.Continent,a.Country,a.City,
```

If you want to further restrict then you can add the conditions in the where clause,
Ex.- For restrict for every country you can add in `Where` clause

```
    AND a.Country = 'Yourcountry'
```

For restrict for every city you can add in `Where` clause

```
     AND a.City = 'Yourcity'
```

You can read more about [Join](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms191517(v=sql.105).aspx) and [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188047.aspx) clause.